# website capture -What means CSS transition to move the DOM?

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping, screenshot, screen-scraping

I am trying to build a web image shooter, or a website capture and the current open source tools don't really work well. 
I am using currently Node webshot

```
var webshot = require('webshot');

webshot('google.com', 'google.png', function(err) {
  // screenshot now saved to google.png
});
```

Applitools.com takes care of scroll of loading infinte scroll and floating header, the tool works well and I found some information online that say that they do

**CSS transition  to move the DOM, to take the screenshot**

Can anyone give heads up on how this is done? What they mean by 'CSS transition  to move the DOM'

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Thank you Barmar, but trying understand how they did it.

Comment: If you want to know how *they* did it, you should read the source code. It's not an appropriate question here.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, but there is not the way to read a source code if it happens in the background. I am trying to learn he technology. Do you have a suggestion where I can ask this question then?